# How to image upload and save ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor5

How to image upload and save ckeditor5?
This is my code.

```js
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor5' ), {

      ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: '/inserimage'
        }   
         })
    .then( newEditor => {
        editor = newEditor;
    } )

    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );

    document.querySelector( '#submit' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    const editorData = editor.getData();
    console.log(editorData);
});
```